# Faster SurfaceTexture.onFrameAvailable callback

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediacodec

I am writing some code that adds a watermark to an already existing video using OpenGL.

I took most of the code from ContinuousCaptureActivity in Grafika - https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

Where instead of using camera to render on a SurfaceTexture, I use the MoviePlayer class, also present in grafika. Also, instead of rendering random boxes, I render the watermark.

I run MoviePlayer at its full speed, i.e., reading from source and rendering on to the surface as soon as a frame is decoded. This does the job for a 30s video in 2s or less.

Now the issue comes with onFrameAvailable callback. It is called only once after every 4 or 5 frames are rendered by the MoviePlayer class. This makes me lose frames in the output video. Now if I make the MoviePlayer thread go to sleep until the corresponding onFrameAvailable is called, everything is fine and no frames are missed. However, now processing my 30s video takes around 5s.

My question is how do I make SurfaceTexture faster? Or is there some completely different approach that I have to look into?

Note that I do not need to render anything on the screen.